# How do I enter an Array Formula in Excel for Mac 2015?

Tags: excel, macos

My Excel install is version 15.27. I have seen people say that I need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but neither of these do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

SHIFT+CMD+Enter is what I use and work fine, make sure you are pressing the keys right after you finished typing the formula